# Javascript: validating form fields by regular expression and using if/else statement

Tags: javascript

In my program I have created form and fields in form. I am trying to validate fields. For that I have used regular expression though my regular expression is correct but regular expression for phone doesn't execute. Can anyone tell me wether I defined if/else statement for validation correctly ?

code:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var zip = document.myform.zip;
  var email = document.myform.email;
  var phone = document.myform.phone;
  if (email.value == "") {
    window.alert("Please enter email Address.");
    state.focus();
    return false;
  }

  var regEx2 = /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/;

  if (zip.value.match(regEx2)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    window.alert("Please provide a zip in the ##### or #####-#### format.");
    zip.focus();
    return false;
  }

  var regEx = /^(?:\(\d{3}\)\s|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/;

  if (phone.value.match(regEx)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    window.alert("Please enter Telephone number in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format.");
    phone.focus();
    return false;
  }


}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Zip</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="zip" maxlength="15" size="28" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Telephone number</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="phone" size="28" placeholder="(555) 555-5555" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"> EMail </td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="email" size="28" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here -

```
 if (zip.value.match(regEx2)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    window.alert("Please provide a zip in the ##### or #####-#### format.");
    zip.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

You are returning from this point regardless of valid or invalid zip. Code blocks afterward won't get executed.

I would suggest not to return in every successful **if block**, because, the code execution will return from that point without validating the other fields.

```
       function validateForm() {

            var valid = true;
            var zip = document.myform.zip;
            var email = document.myform.email;
            var phone = document.myform.phone; 

            if (email.value == "")
            {
                window.alert("Please enter email Address.");
                email.focus();
                valid = false;
            }   

            var regEx2 = \^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$\;

            if(!zip.value.match(regEx2))
            {
                window.alert( "Please provide a zip in the ##### or #####-#### format." );
                zip.focus() ;
                valid = false;
            }  

            var regEx = \^(?:\(\d{3}\)\s|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$\;

            if(!phone.value.match(regEx)) 
            {  
                window.alert("Please enter Telephone number in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format.");
                phone.focus();
                valid = false;  
            }  

            return valid;
       }
```

**if you really want to validate one field only when all the previous fields are valid (as your current code), this is working -**

```
         function validateForm() {

            var zip = document.myform.zip;
            var email = document.myform.email;
            var phone = document.myform.phone; 

            if (email.value == "")
            {
                window.alert("Please enter email Address.");
                email.focus();
                return false;
            }   

            var regEx2 = \^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$\;

            if(!zip.value.match(regEx2))
            {
                window.alert( "Please provide a zip in the ##### or #####-#### format." );
                zip.focus() ;
                return false;
            }  

            var regEx = \^(?:\(\d{3}\)\s|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$\;

            if(!phone.value.match(regEx)) 
            {  
                window.alert("Please enter Telephone number in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format.");
                phone.focus();
                return false;
            }  

            return true;
         }
```

Here is the complete script -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>NumerValidation</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form name="myform" id="myform" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
        <tr>
                <td align="right">Zip</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="zip" maxlength="15" size="28"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Telephone number</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="phone" size="28" placeholder="(555) 555-5555"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right"> EMail </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="email" size="28" /></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td align="right"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </form>
<script>

         function validateForm() {

            var zip = document.myform.zip;
            var email = document.myform.email;
            var phone = document.myform.phone; 

            if (email.value == "")
            {
                window.alert("Please enter email Address.");
                email.focus();
                return false;
            }   

            var regEx2 = /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/;

            if(!zip.value.match(regEx2))
            {
                window.alert( "Please provide a zip in the ##### or #####-#### format." );
                zip.focus() ;
                return false;
            }  

            var regEx = /^(?:\(\d{3}\)\s|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/;

            if(!phone.value.match(regEx)) 
            {  
                window.alert("Please enter Telephone number in (xxx) xxx-xxxx format.");
                phone.focus();
                return false;
            }  

            return true;
         } 

        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On the other hand, your code makes unnecessary regex checks even if the first validations fail, by not breaking execution upon regex matches.

Comment: I mean, unless OP's intent is to show the three alerts in case email, zip and phone's values are all invalid

Comment: @shakhawat it should show alert message for any blank field or incorrect value upon submit button

Comment: @shakhawat my code doesn't check for phone field. my regular expression is correct but still I don't know why

Comment: @shakhawat Do I only need to add return true once ? I can add as many if I want ?

Comment: Displaying three alerts in a row is kind of annoying for users. Displaying all validation errors in a single alert is nicer.

Comment: Best practice is showing no alert for validation at all, show them in an error div just beside the field. A user just misspelled something, we should not punish with the alert for that.

Comment: @pari, check my edited answer now, I have noted the problem with your code

Comment: @ shakhawat if user doesn't enter anything or enter wrong data and click on submit then upon clicking ok on alert it should be close and focus on that field to enter/correct data.

Comment: @ shakhawat it shouldn't open alert in a row.

Comment: I have posted 2 version of the function, the 2nd one doesn't open alerts in a row

Comment: @shakhawat second version doesn't open alert at all

Comment: when i click submit without entering anything it should show alert and by pressing ok on alert it should focus on that field to enter/correct data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157213/discussion-between-shakhawat-and-pari).

Comment: you have to put a ; at the end of onsubmit="return validateForm();"